# "I did go to school" vs. "I went to school"

Tags: verbs

During the 2005 Stanford Commencement, Steve Jobs said "Seventeen years later I did go to school". Is this incorrect usage or is there any difference between "I did go" and "I went"?

Comment: Are you sure that Jobs said it like that? The quote was: " And 17 years later I did go to college." The context will make a difference.

Comment: It's perfectly legitimate English, and quite appropriate in the proper context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "did + verb" and just "verb+ed"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118683/difference-between-did-verb-and-just-verbed)

Comment: vanderpn was right: this clearly did duplicate that previous post

Answer (score 10):

These days,"I *did* go to school," is only correct in the context of providing emphasis, if Jobs was perhaps saying that for some reason, earlier on in his life, he *hadn't* gone to school. 
If emphasis isn't necessary, then, "I went to school," is enough.

http://www.michellehenry.fr/emphasize.htm

Answer (score 1):

What Jobs is saying is

> Seventeen years later I did *(finally)* go to college.
>   *seventeen years later I did finally finish my college education*

He was saying that he finally completed college education which he had started at one point.

Jobs had gone to [college earlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs#Reed_College) and it would have been appropriate for him to characterize it by saying

> I went to college.

but he never finished and this is why he emphasized *did go to college*